# How to create 360 Stereographic fisheye video or little planet video from equi-rectangle projection?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, opengl-es

I have streaming images that are equi-rectangular projection.  I would like to show it as little planet view.  I tried to search for examples of it, but couldn't find any.  Does anyone know how to create 360 Stereographic fisheye video or little planet video from equi-rectangle projection using OpenGL ES in IOS? Android?  Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of examples here:

https://www.shadertoy.com/results?query=fisheye

Those shaders are not OpenGL ES but very similar, you only need to change some input.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am not very familiar with shader and not sure how to apply it for my solution, yet.